# Stream only audio track from mp4 file

Tags: ios, streaming, mp4

I have a remote MP4 file that has video and sound. I want to only stream the audio track of the mp4 file. I don't need the video and want to decrease the internet usage in my app. I have no idea where to start with this, Google doesn't seem to help. Is this impossible? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't... If you want audio only, you need to split video / audio on the server or put a stream software (like vlc, ffmpeg or mplayer) who can re-encode file in realtime (so you can drop video for new stream)

It's better, for me, to process all files on server and extract audio track...